# Give textfield a value based on option selected from drop down

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

What I'm trying to do is give my textfield a value based an an option is select form my drop down. For example: I have 2 fields, a drop down and a textfield. I select Facebook from the dropdown and the value "http://www.facebook.com/" appears in my textfield. How can I achieve this effect? I know that I have to call a function onchange of the drop down but that's pretty much everything I know. Remember that I'm not trying to copy the exact selected value from the dropdown to the textfield here.

Comment: Please post you code you have so far or an example - jsfiddle

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**example markup**

```
<select>
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</option>
    <option value="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</option>
</select>

<input type="text" />
```

**jquery**

```
$('select').change(function() {
    $('input[type="text"]').val(this.value);
});
```

#### [Here's a fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/38xcG/1/)

---

In response to your comment, there are a number of ways to do it (a `switch` statement, `if/elseif` statement etc), the easiest would probably be to create an object mapping the `text` to the corresponding `url`:

```
var urlFromText = {
  'Facebook' : 'http://www.facebook.com/',
  'Twitter' : 'http://www.twitter.com/'
};
```

Then, in your `change` handler, you can simply use:

```
$('input[type="text"]').val(urlFromText[$('option:selected', this).text()]);
```

#### [Here's an example](http://jsfiddle.net/deifwud/38xcG/2/)

Comment: Thanks for your answer! This works perfect but I don't want the value to be a URL so it has to be done in another way. How could this be tweaked so the drop down option doesn't need the URL as value?

Answer (score 0):

**HTML**

```
<select id="network">
    <option value="http://www.facebook.com">Facebook</div>
    <option value="http://www.twitter.com">Twitter</div>
</select>
<input id="network-txt"/>
```

**Jquery**

```
$("#network").change(function(){
    $("#network-txt").val($(this).val());
});
```

**Working Example** http://jsfiddle.net/nVEEE/