# using dropdown label to validation other dropdown value

Tags: javascript, php, validation, dropdown

I have two dropdowns:

```
<select name="first_value" id="first_value">
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_jan" ?>">January</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_feb" ?>">February</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_mar" ?>">March</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_apr" ?>">April</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_may" ?>">May</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_june" ?>">June</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_july" ?>">July</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_aug" ?>">August</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_sept" ?>">September</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_oct" ?>">October</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_nov" ?>">November</option>
    <option value="<?php print"$sum_dec" ?>">December</option>
</select>
```

and

```
<select name="month" id="month">
    <option>January</option>
    <option>February</option>
    <option>March</option>
    <option>April</option>
    <option>May</option>
    <option>June</option>
    <option>July</option>
    <option>August</option>
    <option>September</option>
    <option>October</option>
    <option>November</option>
    <option>December</option>
</select>
```

The JavaScript for these dropdowns:

```
function validateForm() {
  var a = document.forms["myForm"]["first_value"].value;
  var b = document.forms["myForm"]["month"].value;
  var c = document.forms["myForm"]["sec_value"].value;

  if (a != b) {
    alert("Month isn't Same");
    $("#month").focus();
    return false;
  } else {
    if (c == "") {
      alert("Recently sold item empty");
      $("#sec_value").focus();
      return false;
    }
  }
}
```

I've been trying adding labels to first_value (i.e `label="January"` and so on),
or both, and change `.value` to `.label`, or using `.option` in validation script, but still doesn't work. It just passes without error, even when `first_value.label` and `month.label` do not match.

I need `first_value` value in my form to post the `sum_value` and `month` to post the month.

Later in the action form I want it become like this:

```
$first_value=$_post['first_value'];
$sec_value=$_post['sec_value']
$final_value=$fist_value+$sec_value
$month = month
```

If I'm not using validation, it's already done I think, nothing to do more, but 
I still need it match the month that user wants to choose, for updating data.
`first_value` is sum all data in the month and when the updating process works, it's really updating the correct month, in case someone picks a wrong month.

Comment: where are you calling validat.... function, Or is it kept as is in script tag? Any specific reason to use javascript syntax   document.forms["myForm"]["first_value"].value;   where you can use $("#first_value").val()

Comment: yeah, it kept in script tag.

not have any specific reason, since that the only one i know,
i'v been try making fully working site for school project.
this problem was the last, been trying search all over the google and found nothing similiar, so i decide to post it here

Comment: It wont work untill you call it on any event? Say any button click event or  form submit,

Comment: no, anything i do/change .value / .label / .option
it won't work, it just pass the validation
even when first_value and month isn't match

Answer (score 0):

Sample html showing how you can call validate function, also prevent default form submit.

NOTE: You must do changes based on your requirement, I am trying  to explain how you can call validate function

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<head>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script>
function validateForm(e) {

e.preventDefault();//change

var a = document.forms["myForm"]["first_value"].value;
var b = document.forms["myForm"]["month"].value;
var c = document.forms["myForm"]["sec_value"].value;

if (a != b) {
   alert("Month isn't Same");
   $("#month").focus();
   return false;
}else{
   if (c == "") {
   alert("Recently sold item empty");
   $("#sec_value").focus();
   return false;
    }
  }
}
</script>
$(document).ready(function(){
    $("form").submit(function(e){
        validateForm(e);// your function
    });
});
</script>
</head>
<body>

<form id="myForm" action=""><!--your form, you should add your elements in form-->
  <!--your select boxes should be placed here-->
  <input type="submit" value="Submit">
</form> 

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: im already know how to calling the validation
what i ask is, what i should do or change 
so my validation work


<form method="post" onsubmit="return validateForm()" enctype="multipart/form-data" name="myForm" target="_blank">

the textfield/textarea/dropdown here

<input name="auth" type="submit" value="Update">
<form>

Comment: or if you have some related tutorial about this kind problem, tell me. i'll do the research

Comment: Please provide full html, Also make sure you write you prevent default form submit using below syntax  onsubmit="return validateForm(e)", e.preventDefault();

Comment: Your form is doing default submit thus bypassing the validation.

Comment: here the full yet not full code
https://paste.ofcode.org/FDmp2sn3vWnEHWjZ4VaRfL

i remove other line other than line for that form

Comment: Have you tried preventing default form submit , kindly refer my last comment and also updated answer ,. Let me know once checked

Comment: i write the code isn't use english, so from your point of view some word maybe seem weird to read.

Comment: the real prob here is

var a = document.forms["myForm"]["first_value"].value;
var b = document.forms["myForm"]["month"].value;

first_value and month clearly have different value,

   first value is 'number' i get from sum_month    and
month is word, Month.

   if i just remove sum_month in first_value ,
when i run the scrip, it fine, validation working,

Comment: Check in the browser ,inside elements tab of debugger that whether first drop-down is getting generated correctly with expected values

Comment: yeah its correct.
show what i want ,

first_value is number, from sum,
month is word, number,

clearly have different value, but by validation scrip i write, it use .value, to validate each other.
and when i use label, it just pass validation even the label in both not same

Comment: is it actually possible use label in dropdown and use it later for validation?

Comment: Try $(".Classname).val() to get the values of elements.  And then check

Comment: if i just reverse the place for month and sum_value in first value, i think that will do the trick, but, again, feel weird in my eyes

Comment: i decided use other method to display sum_month value, since using dropdown label seems not working. 
decided use something like this 
https://stackoverflow.com/questions/16539155/give-textfield-a-value-based-on-option-selected-from-drop-down